# What is the problem with this review queue audit question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was going through the low quality posts queue when I had to review the audit answer below. I first thought it was an audit with a high quality post pretending to be flagged, but it ended up being the opposite and gave me the good old warning:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You
>   didn't pass. This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive
>   nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable

Can anyone tell me why this question was deleted? I do not know if it is the correct answer to the question but it seems to be correctly formatted, without any quality issues.

## The answer:

> You can solve this problem using the IntegralUI TabStrip directive. There is an article: [Dynamically Populate Tabs from JSON in AngularJS](https://www.example.com/Placeholder__This_is_not_the_actual_URL_used_in_the_post), where tabs are loaded from a JSON file. You can use the code from the article and by little modification you can make it work in your case.
>
> Basically, you need to set up how tab content is displayed. For example from your data structure, you can use this:
>
> ```
> $scope.tabs = [
>    {
>        countryId : 1, 
>        name: 'France',
>        country: 'France',
>        content: [
>            { name: 'Paris' },
>            { name: 'Marseille' }
>        ]
>    },
>    {
>        countryId : 2, 
>        name: 'England',
>        country: 'England',
>        content: [
>            { name: 'London' },
>            { name: 'Southampton' }
>        ]
>    }
> ];
> ```
>
> The HTML looks like:
>
> ```
> <iui-tabstrip name="{{ctrlName}}" class="directive" tabs="tabs">
>    <iui-tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" name="{{tab.name}}" heading="{{tab.country}}">
>        <ul class="country-list">
>            <li ng-repeat="city in tab.content">
>                <span>{{city.name}}</span>&nbsp;
>            </li>
>        </ul>
>    </iui-tab>
> </iui-tabstrip>
> ```
>
> And show the cities in one line:
>
> ```
> .country-list li
> {
>    display: inline-block;
>    margin: 10px 0;
> }
> ```

[Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33618593/dynamically-populate-tabs-with-the-right-content-in-angularjs/34091055#34091055)

Review link (can people other than me access it?): https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21954747

Comment: The answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive.

Comment: Alright, but do you know why ?

Comment: We can't see why something was flagged.

Comment: That user is currently suspended so I guess they spamed this link on a lot of questions.

Comment: I don’t see this as spam either. The answer itself attempts to answer the question; the link actually links to a relevant article. This audit should be removed.

Comment: Quite the mystery. If it was true spam, it sat there over 3 years without being detected. It also hasn't been edited. Also can't find anything on that domain on MetaSmoke. Certainly strange. I guess the user started spamming recently and that got this older answer deleted as well.

Comment: This and similar posts was marked as spam due to a moderator discovering that all posts by the user since 2012 (except one), contains links to that specific domain without disclosing affiliation.

Comment: Sorry @Samuel, but how can a mere mortal know that?

Comment: how it works: posts are marked as spam, but when reviewing a single post, you cannot know that. Then since it's spam, it's valid for the audit system, and you can stumble (and trip) on this.

Comment: @iBug The only way to catch non-blatant spam in the review queues is to go to the question and see that the answer was deleted, or to go to the user and see that the user was deleted/banned/etc.  Yes this is cheesing the review system; but since robot-reviewers don't do so and get trapped the powers that be are OK with our doing so.

Comment: This is a years-old flaw in the selection of audits.

Comment: @iBug: They can’t. Audits have a lot of problems.

Comment: Part of the absurdity of VLQ audits is that they're populated with spam but you *can't flag something as spam* from the VLQ queue, and the [only guidance I know of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191860#comment775002_191860) on how to handle spam there is that it's important that spam gets deleted through spam flags and that it should *not* get deleted through the VLQ queue. As such, the right way to handle spam there (not that I recall seeing any that wasn't an audit) is, I think, to choose "Looks OK" and then spam flag it from a new tab. The audits actually enforce the wrong behaviour.

Comment: @MarkAmery I prefer this solution https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is, IMHO, a poor audit item. The problem with the answer is that it contained spam... which is normally obvious and an OK reason to use the post as an audit. It's not a good fit in this case, however, because the spam is not detectable as spam without access to a broader context that you as a normal user don't have access to:

A bunch of posts from the same person all contained a link to the same site without some attribution. It's problematic for you because:

1. You can't search these other posts by the user via their profile page because the user is deleted.
2. Even if the user weren't deleted, you wouldn't be able to see the other deleted posts because you can't search for deleted posts by other users.
3. Even if you could search for deleted posts by other users, you don't even have 10k reputation, so you can't see *any* deleted posts by other users even if you stumble upon them.

By the way, other users *can* see the review audit you linked to, but we can't see what state it was in when it was presented to you (e.g. what 'fake' score or tags may have been added). The only clue that it might have been an audit, aside from clicking through to the question (which is something I strongly encourage every time, even/especially for moderators), would have been the posted date of the answer and question.

Assuming the post date wasn't tampered with by the system to hide its true state, you would have seen that the answer was posted in 2015. Old stuff doesn't typically show up in the Low Quality Post queue... the LQP queue is usually filled with posts users are seeing while browsing the site. If you see a post that is older than, say, a year showing up in the LQP queue, it *could* be genuine, but it's best to click through on those occasions to make sure you're looking at a real review item rather than an audit.

Comment: but, but, you're giving tricks to cheat the audit... GOOD!! after 11000 reviews I'm beggining to feel slightly annoyed by audits & bans.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Audits are not there to trick you or make you fail, but to make sure you're paying attention. So if an audit or potential audit makes you stop and click through to the actual question... that's the audit doing it's job. This is not to say that I necessarily agree that that's a good system to use, however...

Comment: I wasn't being completely honest there :) Audits are necessary, but it's difficult to pick ones where there is no ambiguity. It's better to remove the ambiguous ones manually.

Comment: I also remember that the rare times I've been banned from review, I didn't "robo review", looked carefully (but didn't visit the link), and made the wrong choice...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre review bans require multiple failures in quick succession (e.g. more than two in a short period of time/number of reviews). I agree it's difficult to pick audits and it should be a totally human process in the first place, IMHO, but a review ban isn't just for robo-reviewing... it's also for 'wrong' reviewing. Those cases are rarer, but perhaps *more* important than banning robo-reviewers... because you can probably provide a good reason for why you reviewed the way you did. Those cases often require discussion so that the banned user can change their reviewing perspective.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't know the exact criteria for banning, of course, but I do know I have failed at least several dozen CV Queue audits in my time and never been banned, though to be fair only 17 people have done more CV Queue reviews than me on Stack Overflow... so maybe a few dozen is not that many in comparison?

Comment: I'm also on the top reviewers for VLQ, I suppose that failing 2 or 3 audits _in a row_ qualifies for a ban.

Comment: FWIW, I "cheat" on *lots* of audits in the way Tyler suggests here. From a pure time perspective, it works out. It takes me a couple of seconds to open a post in a new tab and check if it's an audit, but sometimes takes several minutes to read and evaluate a post of any length. I don't want to waste my time doing such reading and thinking for no actual reason, so when I see long posts in the queue I open them in a new tab immediately to check if they're audits.

Answer (score 4):

Let's explicitly capture [this point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379066/what-is-the-problem-with-this-review-queue-audit-question#comment663360_379066) for posterity's sake.

> This and similar posts was marked as spam due to a moderator discovering that all posts by the user since 2012 (except one), contains links to that specific domain without disclosing affiliation.
>
> – Samuel Liew♦

The whole point of audits is to make sure you were paying attention.  Irrespective of if you were or not, circumstances like *this* come out of left field.  At least the moderators are understanding, and hopefully this won't impact you permanently.

I will also state:  the link *did* look suspicious, but it wasn't the case that it was a clear-cut pattern of spam or blatant advertising.  The review queues aren't built for that kind of thing right now, and I don't think they'll ever be, really.

Comment: I won't be deleting my comment under the question. Just wanted to get the discussion started around this issue with some background instead of just speculation.

Comment: @SamuelLiew:  I trust that you'd keep it around.  This is more for the discussion point of, "This is why audits can burn you."  If you'd like a better spot to put this, that's fine, but this is one of those gotchas with the audit queue that happens more than it should and it should be well broadcast until the issue's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The audit might not be one of the best (actually it could the other way around), however giving the quality of the answer (good english, contains code snippets, explains), one could wonder how such a post ended in the low quality posts queue.

Posts like this are unlikely to end up in this queue, when you encounter them better to check them out, to see what's the real state of the post.

Checking the post doesn't mean cheating, I'd say it's actually what the designers of the audit system want from you: instead of robo-accepting or robo-denying the flags you're actually taking time to see the state of the post.