# Suggestion: warn or don't use old posts for audits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

Following the case of [What is the problem with this review queue audit question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379066/what-is-the-problem-with-this-review-queue-audit-question), I'd like to highlight that if a post survived for weeks without being flagged, then it's unlikely that it's in a state easily identifiable as being *spam*. Actually, if an old post is marked as spam, then it's likely to be for a reason that even attentive reviewers can't find out from the review page itself. For instance, in the linked case, post was 3 years old and the reason for spam was "*repeated undisclosed affiliation*", but this aspect of repetition can't be discovered from the review page itself.

I'm aware that many on Meta, from experience, recommend reviewers to *look outside the review pages to systematically discern audits*, but if we could have self-contained audits (discernible from the review page itself), that would give more fairness to reviewers. Otherwise, honest reviewers, falling into seemingly invisible traps, will be discouraged or will recourse to scripts to bypass audits altogether.

Suggestion: if a post is **more than 9 days old** and is marked as spam:

- either don't use it for audits
- or warn on the audit page that the post was marked as spam, to hint reviewers

Comment: Why 9 days old?

Comment: 9 days old today, or 9 days old at the time of getting flagged?

Comment: This just mixes up the need for review with the need for audits.  Audits were deemed necessary because reviewers are not paying enough attention.  Robo-clicking is a big problem, they fail the audit when they reject a concerned user's flag and didn't pay enough attention.  The advice is "stop, look, listen".  They didn't look and notice the post isn't there anymore.  Easiest audit to pass, they fail them all the time anyway.  Not much inclined to listen either, at least at meta when it is the nth audit they failed and got banned.  Age is quite irrelevant.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but you get a banner stating explicitly that the content is marked as spam and to take extra care reviewing it. This is still true in an audit, although it may be not actually true. If you don't go to look at the actual question even then... well then you have a gambling problem.

Answer (score 5):

Can we just leave it at

> if a post is marked for spam, don't use it for audits

...because not all spam is created equal.

Comment: Then what *do* you want to use for audits? R/A is also out because we don't want to needlessly shove offensive content in peoples faces.

Comment: Surely there exists a qualifier for different kinds of spam, then.  I realize that my blanket statement may have been a bit hasty...but the issue is a layman is at a keen disadvantage when it comes to certain reviews.  Reference my answer in the linked question for an example.  Those burns don't heal quickly.

Comment: I guess the  "burn" part is somewhat individual. I personally consider the rate or invalid audits sufficiently low, esp. for an automated system. But maybe that's specific to the queues I frequent (LQQ, CVQ, and edit queue).